# Building a order inventory and submitting multiple orders

Tags: lists, e-commerce, ordering, inventory

I am building an e-commerce site (office suppliers with 1000 products).

Any organization can register with us and build an inventory. Say an XYZ.org has registered with us and 100 products (pen, pencil, paper, eraser...) has been added to the inventory.

Now admin from XYZ.org wanted to order 40 products.

How will I help the admin to build an order from the available 100 products?

Comment: I dont understand whats going on here which probably means its not as intuitive as it should be

Comment: OK, now I get it

Comment: When you write that "XYZ org has registered with us and 100 products... has been add to the inventory," does that mean that XYZ typically re-orders those 100 products?  Is this like their wishlist that gets replenished?

Answer (score 2):

You could treat this similar to an ecommerce system that has "wishlist" facility in addition to ordering using a cart system.

Hence admin can add the 100 items to a wishlist. Whenever admin is ready to order, wishlist is browsed and items required added to cart.

Wishlist should have ability to order by for instance, aplhabetically, product type, price, etc. Also you should provide a search facility.

Answer (score 0):

You could render out the complete list alphabetically and let the user input quantity beside each product. You can easily break up the list into collapsible alphebetic groups.

I like the idea of seeing all products without having to type

edit: will work when number products per customer is low but if products is in the 1000's you'll need a look up pattern.

Comment: if there are 100 products you want me to list all the 100 products alphabetical in a collapsible group (accordion) ?

Comment: yep. but 100 is the fringe use case. Whats the most common scenario do you reckon?

Comment: ok, so ive read again and you say the owner could have 1000's products. if you have wordpress, their method of typing and adding tags as look ahead matches is quite nice

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to look at a solution for mobile too.

Comment: mobile: this is an admin interface. I doubt users will be using the interface in the same way on mobile and would be using it for different use cases. Just bear that in mind.

Comment: Yh but they should be able to use it on mobile too. Because we are developing it with bootstrap.

Comment: bootstrap is responsive so thats not an issue as far as layout is concerned

Answer (score 0):

If the list might be a thousand products, you can presume that the admin might want to browse the whole list and choose any number of products arbitrarily. So in my view the ability to easily traverse through the list of items is key. Once the admin is convinced that she's interested in a product, she should be able to view details of that product without moving away from the list.

Once admin chooses an item to add to the order, you can just do an 'Add to Order' not unlike how a shopping cart works. Quantity of each product can be edited later on once all the products are in the cart, and same goes for delivery date etc.